# Change audio stream of Exoplayer 2's PlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a toggle button on video that, when pressed, should lower the volume of the user's currently playing music but raise the volume of the `PlayerView`, and vice versa when the video is playing. Here is the method assigned to that button:

```
    private val exoPlayerView: PlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toroPlayerViewFull)
    private val audioManager = itemView.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    private val originalMusicVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
    private var helper: ExoPlayerViewHelper? = null

    private fun toggleVolume() {

    exoPlayerView.player?.let {
        if (helper?.volume == 0f) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1, 0)
            helper?.volume = 1f
         
        
        } else {
            helper?.volume = 0f
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, originalMusicVolume, 0)
         
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that the volume set by the helper is independent of the volume set for the AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC stream, as the volume of the player is being muffled to the same volume of the music. I'm assuming this is because the Exoplayer also plays on that stream. Is there any way to change the audio stream of the exoplayer so that its volume can be adjusted independently of the user's music?